# Can I link a Facebook page by its ID even if it does not show up in the autocompletion?

Tags: facebook, facebook-pages

Sometimes a page doesn't show up when trying to link it in a post using the `@name` or `+name` syntax.

Is there any way to link it manually by its ID?

If that's possible, is there a way to specify the title?

For example, lots of band pages have the title "Bandname (Official)" but of course it would be much nicer to link it using just "Bandname".

Comment: I've not managed to link a page, or a person, if it didn't show up in the autocompletion.